How can I get the code to cooldown and retry a request when I recieve a JSONDecode Error?
I am trying to gather a lot of data for a project using NBA API.
The inputAPIdata stores all the details needed to produce the NBA API outputs. All of the functions used are coded by me and request the data from different NBA API endpoints.
for index in range(startNum,len(inputAPIData)):
    currentSeason,playerID,teamID,oppTeamId,hOrA,dayBeforeAPIformat=inputAPIData[index]
    rowInputData=[[index,hOrA]]
    print(index)
    print(inputAPIData[index])
    #print(getLastXGames(5,currentSeason,playerID,dayBeforeAPIformat))
    rowInputData.append(getLastXGames(5,currentSeason,playerID,dayBeforeAPIformat))
    time.sleep(0.3)
    rowInputData.append(getSeasonStats(playerID))
    time.sleep(0.3)
    rowInputData.append(getCareerStatsPerSeason(playerID))
    time.sleep(0.3)
    rowInputData.append(getTeamStats(currentSeason,dayBeforeAPIformat,teamID,5))
    time.sleep(0.3)
    rowInputData.append(gettingTeamPtsPerGame(2,currentSeason,teamID,dayBeforeAPIformat))
    time.sleep(0.3)
    rowInputData.append(getTeamHead2Head(teamID,oppTeamId,currentSeason,3))
    if -1 not in rowInputData:
        inputDataBigList.append(rowInputData)
        #converting data from groups into 1D
        rowInputData1D=[]
        for x in rowInputData:
            for y in x:
                rowInputData1D.append(y)

        f=open('inputData.txt','a')
        f.write(str(rowInputData1D)+"^")
        f.close()
        f=open('indexCounter.txt','w')
        f.write(str(index))
        f.close()

As there are a few thousand data entries, I want to be able to leave this code running without checking up on it constantly. However, every 10 or so iterations of the loop, I recieve this error:
for index in range(startNum,len(inputAPIData)):
    currentSeason,playerID,teamID,oppTeamId,hOrA,dayBeforeAPIformat=inputAPIData[index]
    rowInputData=[[index,hOrA]]
    print(index)
    print(inputAPIData[index])
    #print(getLastXGames(5,currentSeason,playerID,dayBeforeAPIformat))
    rowInputData.append(getLastXGames(5,currentSeason,playerID,dayBeforeAPIformat))
    time.sleep(0.3)
    rowInputData.append(getSeasonStats(playerID))
    time.sleep(0.3)
    rowInputData.append(getCareerStatsPerSeason(playerID))
    time.sleep(0.3)
    rowInputData.append(getTeamStats(currentSeason,dayBeforeAPIformat,teamID,5))
    time.sleep(0.3)
    rowInputData.append(gettingTeamPtsPerGame(2,currentSeason,teamID,dayBeforeAPIformat))
    time.sleep(0.3)
    rowInputData.append(getTeamHead2Head(teamID,oppTeamId,currentSeason,3))
    if -1 not in rowInputData:
        inputDataBigList.append(rowInputData)
        #converting data from groups into 1D
        rowInputData1D=[]
        for x in rowInputData:
            for y in x:
                rowInputData1D.append(y)

        f=open('inputData.txt','a')
        f.write(str(rowInputData1D)+"^")
        f.close()
        f=open('indexCounter.txt','w')
        f.write(str(index))
        f.close()

Often, rerunning the function that throws the error or just waiting half a minute will fix the problem. Is there possibly something wrong with my code or is this a problem to do with the API sometimes does not return an output. If it is the latter, is there any way I can handle this error and fix the error so the code can automatically re-run that function rather than the code being halted.

you need to give the full code. I can;t debug if I can't see everything needed to run this loop.

and to answer your question, yes you could/should include error handling. Look up try/except
